# user specific jobs vs system jobs running as specific users

Tags: debian, ubuntu, cron

On Debian and its derivatives, how shall we understand the following seemingly contradictory facts:

- `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*` have a user field, meaning that a job is running as the user (either root or **nonroot**).
- the jobs in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*` are system jobs not user-specific jobs?

If you want to run a job either as root or as a nonroot user, where would you add the job: `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d/*`, or `/var/spool/cron/crontab/<user>`?

Stephen's comment at [How are files under /etc/cron.d used?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458713/how-are-files-under-etc-cron-d-used#comment876068_458715) clarifies a lot, but I still can't figure that out

> A system job is a job which applies to the whole system. A user-specific job is a job run on behalf of a specific user; typically, tasks which the user would do manually while logged in, but which he/she wishes to perform periodically and automatically — e.g. backups of specific files, or refreshes of remote development repositories, or mail processing, or mirroring web sites

Thanks.

Comment: Surely the description at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478785/5132 of when one would use each of the three already answers this.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for reminding. Meanwhile, if I may, I was wondering about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478998/how-does-anacron-determine-daily-weekly-and-monthly-job-to-run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use the various cron configuration files as follows:

- `/var/spool/cron/crontab` is used by “real” users (*i.e.* users corresponding to humans using the system), edited using `crontab -e`;
- `/etc/cron.d` is used for package-provided cron jobs, which can run as a “system” user (*e.g.* `logcheck` for `logcheck`’s cron jobs); as mentioned in answers to some of your other questions on the topic, `/etc/cron.d` is intended for use by packages, at least on Debian-based systems;
- `/etc/crontab` would be used for locally-defined system jobs, run as root, except that I find `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` more convenient for those.

In my comment, by “user” I meant “human-backed user” (if you’ll allow me the expression). Jobs run as “system users”, root or otherwise, are system jobs in my mind.

From a Debian packaging perspective, Debian Policy describes [the recommended practice](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#cron-jobs) regarding cron jobs: in summary, use `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` if appropriate, `/etc/cron.d` otherwise. It’s therefore normal to see package-provide jobs in all five directories.

Comment: Thanks. Some questions, if I may. (1) "`/etc/cron.d` is used for package-provided cron jobs, which typically run as a “system” user ".  I was wondering why all the cron jobs in my `/etc/cron.d/`  (`anacron`  `popularity-contest`  `sysstat`) are run as `root` instead of nonroot system users? (2) The files under `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` look like per package. So can that be confusing with `/etc/cron.d/*`?

Comment: (3) Suppose I have a bash script to be run  as often as once in 15 minutes, and the script first `sudo service reload` a system service and then calls my program to use the service. Should I put the script in a crontab file in `/etc/cron.d/`, `/etc/crontab`, or `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/t`? Since the script contains `sudo`, shall I run it as myself and provide my password to `sudo`, or run it as `root`?

Comment: I’ve addressed questions 1 and 2 in my update. 3 is a follow-up question IMO (it needs clarification: why does your script have to `sudo`, what is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/t`, are you using systemd?).

Comment: Thanks. (3) I am using Ubuntu, so I guess I am using systemd. My bash script needs `sudo` because it needs to run `sudo service <someservice> reload`. My script is  written by myself, not provided  by a package or the OS, and does that mean that I should run it as myself in a job in my crontab file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/t`? `sudo` will ask for password then.  To avoid providing `sudo` password, shall I run the script as root in a job in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/`? (I am ruling out `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}`, because the script needs to be run once in 15 mins).

Comment: But my script is written by myself, not provided by a package or the OS, so I am sure if it is good practice to specify to run my script in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/`, is it?

Answer (score 3):

The crontabs under `/etc` can only be edited manually by root (or implicitly by root while installing some package).   These crontabs would typically be used to schedule jobs relating to services on the system. Therefore, these are "system jobs".  Some of these services may well run as users other than root.

The spooled crontabs in `/var` are the user specific crontabs.  A user should use `crontab -e` to edit their own personal crontab (this may be a reasonable thing for root to do as well).  A user who is not tied to any specific service on the system (i.e. a human being) should not need to have cron jobs running in their name in the crontabs under `/etc`.