# What do the following lines mean in /etc/cron.daily/automysqlbackup?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm on **Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS** and what I'm trying to do is to set the **cron job** for **automysqlbackup** utility.
When I installed **automysqlbackup** I noticed that the `cron.daily/automysqlbackup` was created inside the `etc` folder. In the `automysqlbackup` file there are the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup || exit 0
/usr/sbin/automysqlbackup
```

Why do we need these and what do they do?

Can I delete that `automysqlbackup` file and set everything up through `sudo crontab -u username -e` for my user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we need these and what do they do?

`#!/bin/sh` specifies that the cron “script” runs with `/bin/sh` (it’s a normal shell script). This is [a shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/86440).

`test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup || exit 0` checks whether `/usr/sbin/automysqlbackup` exists and is executable; if it isn’t, it exits the script silently. This line is useful to avoid an error if `automysqlbackup` is removed but its cron job isn’t — which happens if the package is removed, not purged. Technically, it works as follows: `test -x /usr/sbin/automysqlbackup` exits with code 0 if the file is executable, 1 otherwise. `||` causes the shell to look at the exit code of the previous command; if it’s 0, the rest of the line is ignored, otherwise it’s executed; [`exit 0`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exit) causes the shell to exit with exit code 0 (no error).

`/usr/sbin/automysqlbackup` runs `automysqlbackup`.

> Can I delete that `automysqlbackup` file and set everything up through `sudo crontab -u username -e` for my user?

Yes, you can; the package is set up correctly so that your removal will be remembered, and the file won’t be restored on package upgrades. Note that you don’t need `sudo` here, `crontab -e` as the user works just as well. You will however need to ensure that the user has all the necessary permissions for the backup (in MySQL and in whatever storage the backup goes to).

I would suggest considering instead whether there *is* any particular reason the default daily cron job isn’t appropriate for you; if there isn’t, keep it instead of setting up your own.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to make backups everyday at certain time and delete all the backups older than 30 days. Also I wonder why I couldn't find any information on the `exit` command. I tried `man exit`, but nothing was found. Doesn't the `||` stand for logical OR here? Isn't `#!/bin/sh` just a comment here?

Comment: See the update. The existing `cron.daily` job will run once a day, using whatever configuration you’ve defined for `automysqlbackup`. It should work just fine for your purposes.

Comment: And the last thing. I don't understand the following: `25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )` which is placed inside the `/etc/crontab` file and actually runs the `automysqlbackup` utility daily at 6:25 AM. What is `anacron`?

Comment: `anacron` (see `man anacron`) is a utility which ensures jobs are run at certain intervals, even if the system is powered down. See also [Is it true that “cron.daily runs anacron everyhour”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478803/86440), [How does anacron determine daily, weekly and monthly job to run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478998/86440), [How does anacron work if it's not a daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411051/86440) and related posts.

Comment: `man anacron` returns `No manual entry for anacron` for me. Also `find / -iname 'anacron'` returns nothing.

Comment: Ah right, you don’t have `anacron` installed (which is fine). The crontab entry tests to see whether `anacron` is installed, and if it *isn’t*, runs the `cron.daily` entries using `run-parts`.

Comment: So, if I want to use the script from the `cron.daily` for `automysqlbackup` I just have to modify the `/etc/crontab` file and change `25 6 * * *` to whatever values I need, right? And I want to set the daily/monthly backups as well I'll have to create `/etc/cron.weekly/automysqlbackup`, `/etc/cron.monthly/automysqlbackup` files and modify the corresponding lines in `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: If you want to have *all* your `cron.daily` jobs run at a different time, then yes.

Comment: I don’t think you need anything else for weekly and monthly backups, `automysqlbackup` takes care of them when run daily.

Comment: As explained in the package description, “automysqlbackup creates backup every day, week and month for all of your MySQL database, to a configured folder. There's nothing to do but to install this package, and you'll rest assured that you have a way to go back in the history of your database.” It really is an “install-and-forget” package: you don’t *need* to configure anything.

Comment: If you *do* want to change the defaults, look in `/etc/defaults/automysqlbackup`.

Comment: The thing is that I want it to run at certain time and then to delete the old backups. So I'll have to set another cron job like: `find /home/username/private_files/backups/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: No, you don’t need another cron job for that, you can use `automysqlbackup`’s features. Again, look in `/etc/defaults/automysqlbackup` — you can use a `POSTBACKUP` script.

Comment: I wonder why would they recommend running cron jobs for automysqlbackup out there on many different resources like [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/.cs.cmu.edu/help/content/unix_linux/linux/automysqlbackup.html) or [this](https://oloflarsson.se/backups-for-your-linux-server/) for example if automysqlbackup is a self-contained utility that can do all those things without using any cron jobs at all.

Comment: I can’t read those articles’ authors minds ;-). The second one is from 2012, perhaps the package changed since then. The first one discusses the AutoMySQLBackup tool itself, not the package — it’s the Debian (and Ubuntu) package which sets up the cron jobs for you.

Comment: Incidentally, `automysqlbackup` also rotates backups for you, so you might not need to delete anything. It keeps all monthly backups, the last five weekly backups, and the last week’s daily backups.

Comment: There's `DOWEEKLY` where I can pick the day of the week, but I can't see a way to pick the day of the month to do monthly backups. Also I don't see how can I set the exact time without using cron jobs.

Comment: There’s `DOMONTHLY` as well. And yes, you can’t change the time without changing the cron job; is 6:25 not appropriate?

Comment: Accroding to the [documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/automysqlbackup.8.html) there's no `DOMONTHLY`. `6:25` is not appropriate because I'm currently working on a temporary machine that is not always powered on and at `6:25` in the morning it is actually powered off. That's why I need to change the time.

Comment: The man page is unfortunately incomplete. If your system isn’t always on, `anacron` would be appropriate (instead of trying to find a time when it is guaranteed to be on).

Comment: Apologies, the version of `automysqlbackup` in 20.04 doesn’t support `DOMONTHLY`. Monthly backups always happen on the first day of the month (and will be missed if the system isn’t running on that day).

Comment: So, the manually created cron jobs won't work as well if the system is off and the only way to deal with that is to use anacron, right? Thank you for all the information you've provided. You helped a lot! And sorry for such an extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: Yes, cron jobs only run if `cron` itself is running at the exact time the job specifies. `anacron` makes up for that by keeping track of when jobs last ran, managing jobs per “time unit” (daily, weekly, monthly) instead of tracking specific times, and running them if `cron` hasn’t run them in the last day/week/month.